# How to load php file into div using jQuery Load with passing parameter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, parameter-passing

I've an element `<div id="search_result"></div>`, and then I used `$.ajax` to retrieve some data (search result).

```
$.ajax({
  url: "url to server",
  dataType: "json",
  data: keyword,
  type: "post",
  success: function(data){
    /* load searchResult.php with data as passing parameter to searchResult.php */
    $("#search_result").load("searchResult.php");
  }
});
```

but I wanna load those data of search result to searchResult.php, how it's it,.?
and how I access those parameter in searchResult.php,.?

thanks,.

Comment: How is the output format of "data" (the response of your ajax call) ?

Comment: the output format is json, should I decode it in searchResult.php,.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JS:

```
// ...
dataType: "json",

// pass key/value pairs
data: {keyword: "foobar"},
type: "post",
// ...
```

In your PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['keyword']) && !empty($_POST['keyword'])) {
    echo $_POST['keyword']; // echoes "foobar"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  var value = "value of the data here";  
    $.ajax({
      url: "serchResult.php",
      data: "key="+value,
      type: "post",
      success: function(data){
            $('#search_result').html(data);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var variable=10 ;
 $("#search_result").load("searchResult.php", {"variable": variable});
```

On searchResult.php :

```
 <?php echo $_POST['variable'];?>
```